# Amplify Init tutorial problem initializing project in the cloud

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have been trying to follow this tutorial

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-android-notes-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial/analytics.md

and am running into this error
[image]

I have tried to add more IAM profiles in the AWS console, but I am not seeing them show up as options when I re run amplify init. I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Amplify doesn't pull profiles from AWS when populating the list of available profiles.  You can manually add keys to the ~/.aws/credentials file to have them show up in the CLI.  This is where the profiles are kept for your system (this is not specific to amplify, this is where all aws profile credentials are).

Comment: The profiles are actually in ~/.aws/credentials file.